# usb dvd as a device

Tags: usb, dvd

I'm running Kubuntu 21.10.  I want to treat my USB DVD drive as a device, since that's what Handbrake seems to demand.  But **/dev/sr0** doesn't work, nor does **/dev/usb**.  How can I get around this problem?

Alternatively, can I get Handbrake to convert a video to mp4 when it's in the form of an *iso* file?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo blkid`?

Comment: The only devices shown are the disk devices of the form /dev/nvme0n1px, where x is the partition number.

Comment: Hmm. What is the output of `sudo lsusb`?

Comment: Handbrake either opens the DVD directly upon insertion or it doesn't. I always use ISO files instead that have the bonus advantage of being much faster and doesn't require the USB drive to be connected for hours/days.

Comment: Please see the edits.

Comment: The ISO file is merely an 1:1 "image" of the optical media. For the intended purpose it works exactly as directly from said media. You can convert to anything you want.